# Camel invoking Spring-Data causes AmbiguousMethodCallException during delete

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel, spring-data

I have a Spring-Data MongoDB repository. It's just this:

```
public interface MyDataRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyData, String> {}
```

I am using Camel, and save works fine:

```
.beanRef("myDataRepository","save")  // saves myData from message body
```

But delete fails. Message body is a String, which is the id of a 'myData' object. This is what Spring tells me (my formatting):

```
org.apache.camel.component.bean.AmbiguousMethodCallException: 
 Ambiguous method invocations possible: [
    public final void $Proxy42.delete(java.io.Serializable), 
    public final void $Proxy42.delete(java.lang.Iterable), 
    public final void $Proxy42.delete(java.lang.Object)]. 
 Exchange[Message: 513a3b6c0364f9195eca39ed]
```

I've tried so many permutations, I don't know which ones to call out.
Here are a few easy ones:

```
.beanRef("myDataRepository","delete")
.beanRef("myDataRepository","delete(String)")
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my solution has been to go slightly around the problem.

Switched to use:

```
.beanRef( "myDataRepository", "findOne" )  // lookup based on id in msg body
.beanRef( "myDataRepository", "delete" )   // delete based on object
```

So now I delete using the Object itself, removing the ambiguity. Good enough, but open to other answers that address the issue directly.